# Cómo hacer un JoinColumn de entidad externa JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces, jpa

Lo que pasa es que quiero hacer un `JoinColumn` de las entidades modelo y marca pero que están enlazadas con AUTO, me explico:

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto de compra de autos en los que tengo varias entidades, entre ellas MARCA, MODELO, AUTO y COCHEUSUARIO(hay otras más)
lo que pasa es que la tabla COCHEUSUARIO es la tabla en la que se guardan los registros de las compras de los usuarios y esta a la vez enlazada con AUTO(Atributos como de MODELO Y MARCA) y USUARIO(su nombre).
estas son mis clases:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_auto")
public class Auto  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="a_id")
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Marca marca;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Modelo modelo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Estado estado;

@Column(name="a_anno")
private int anno;

@Column(name="a_combustible")
private String combustible;

@Column(name="a_color")
private String color;

@Column(name="a_traccion")
private String traccion;

@Column(name="u_tipomotor")
private String tipomotor;
}
```

Entidad USUARIO

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Usuario {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_usuario")
private long id;

@Column(name="u_razsoc")
private String razsocial;

@Column(name="u_nombreusu")
private String nombreusu;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="u_fechins")
private Date fechins;

@Column(name="u_clave")
private String clave;

@Column(name="u_telefono")
private String telefono;

@Column(name="u_direccion1")
private String direccion1;

@Column(name="u_direccion2")
private String direccion2;
}
```

Entidad COCHEUSUARIO

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_coche_usuario")
public class CocheUsuario {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="cu_id")
private long id;

@Column(name="cu_fechaaq")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fechaq;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="cu_nomusu" , referencedColumnName= "u_nombreusu" )
private Usuario usuario;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name="cu_anno" ,referencedColumnName= "a_anno"),
        @JoinColumn(name="cu_traccion" ,referencedColumnName= "a_traccion"),
        @JoinColumn(name="cu_tipomotor" ,referencedColumnName= "a_tipomotor"),
        @JoinColumn(name="cu_color" ,referencedColumnName= "a_color"),
        @JoinColumn(name="cu_precio", referencedColumnName = "a_precio" )
        })
private Auto auto;

}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es enlazar los atributos de modelo y marca, provenientes de la entidad AUTO

Answer (score 1):

Pues lo estas haciendo mal, no le pongas el *value*, hazlo de la siguiente manera:

```
@JoinColumns(
{
    @JoinColumn(name="cu_anno" ,referencedColumnName= "a_anno"),
    @JoinColumn(name="cu_traccion" ,referencedColumnName= "a_traccion"),
    @JoinColumn(name="cu_tipomotor" ,referencedColumnName= "a_tipomotor"),
    @JoinColumn(name="cu_color" ,referencedColumnName= "a_color"),
    @JoinColumn(name="cu_precio", referencedColumnName = "a_precio" )
})
private Auto auto;
```